# How to hide the Featured Column from Broadleaf Site

Tags: html, e-commerce, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I m building a E-commerce website based on Broadleaf template.I want to remove the Featured column from the right side of the website ??

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using demo site which is located at : https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite
you could indeed remove this section  :

`/site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/catalog/product.html`

from `<section id="right_column">`

`<header>Featured Products</header>
    <div id="options">
         <div class="section">
             <blc:related_products productId="${product.id}"/>
             <ul id="featured_products" class="group">
                 <li th:each="relatedProduct : ${relatedProducts}" th:object="${relatedProduct.relatedProduct}" th:include="catalog/partials/productListItem" class="product_container"></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>`

but probably a complete removal of featured product will be achieved by searching for `blc:related_products` into source code and you'll find it into 4 files : `site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/content/default.html`, `site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/catalog/product.html`, `site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/catalog/category.html`, `site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/catalog/search.html`

but remember this processor only removes the call for finding featured products for different contexts, like featured products linked to a category or to a product, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a `<section id="right_column">` tag in product.html.If i remove this tag the right pannel is removed from site.Any other better solution ??

Answer (score -1):

1. CSS #right_column {display:none} or in template search for div with id right_column

Comment: According to my requirement i need to remove the right pannel completely from the system.Your ans will only hide it,wont remove it.